# Vim replace preVARIABLETEXTpost with VARIABLETEXT?

Tags: vim, replace

Using Vim, I'd like to be able to replace `preVARIABLETEXTpost` with `VARIABLETEXT` in a single command. The reason is that `pre` and `post` might exist elsewhere in the file, and `VARIABLETEXT` changes.

Something like:

> :%s/preGRABTEXTpost/GRABTEXT/g

Essentially I'm trying to strip `pre` and `post` when it exists with some text between them on a single line, though it might exist more once on a single line. I just don't know how to make something like a temporary variable . . . help? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:%s/\v<pre(.{-1,})post>/\1/g
```

could work, depending a bit on your input. For me, it changes:

```
preAApost preBBpost
preCCpost preDDpost
preEEpost
prepost
```

to:

```
AA BB
CC DD
EE
prepost
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` regex operator means "anything". The `+` means "at least once, but possibly more". Therefore:

```
:%s/pre(.+)post/\1/g
```

This will, unfortunately, match this as one group:

> preGRABTEXTpostMORETEXTwibbleEVENMORETEXTpost

To fix that, we make it lazy by using the `?` operator:

```
:%s/pre(.+?)post/\1/g
```

The parentheses tell vim to select that portion as a group and number it. As we only have one group, it's numbered `1`. We then use `\1` in the replacement to signify we want to use it. This should do it.

Comment: In VIM there the lazy `+` does not go like `+?`, but like `\{-1,\}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do this for a particular variable, say the one under your cursor, you can map a command. For instance:

```
:map mm eb"aywo<esc>^Di:%s/pre<ESC>"apapost/<ESC>"apa/g<ESC>"zdd@z
```

Would map the key combination 'mm' to search for the text under your cursor surrounded by pre and post. Helpful if you've got several variables existing between pre/post text and only want to get rid of a particular one.

Answer (score -1):

Edited :
    :%s/pre(.{-})post/\1/g

does the trick

Comment: No, it does not. It fails for the "multiple per line" case.